# Website redirecting to google maps on iphone?

Tags: php, iphone, google-maps

I have an embedded google map in my website's homepage. It was embedded using the google maps embed code I got from the maps site.

Whenever I open that page on my iPhone for some reason it opens the google maps app, minimizing the website.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you won't use the Google api directly. Don't just embedded the map in your website. Use this great tutorial to make it work: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=iw&csw=1

A much quicker solution would be to use google ip 173.194.34.165 instead of google.com in your url. As far as I know the map app won't pick that up.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [static map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) (simple, non interactive) or use the [API directly](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) (complicated).

This seems to be a Google "feature".

Answer (score 0):

This is a google feature. You can find more info here https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3006766?hl=en

I would suggest you to add a link to the map, which when clicked on phone will open the map in google maps app.